# h2o neural net structure. Or: How do you convert an H2o model into a Keras model in R?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, h2o

So I wrote a script that takes the weights of a h2o model and plants them into a keras model. I then found that the results from running the model through keras do not match up with h2o.
[image: h2o model gives different results from keras with the same weights]

Here's the code I used to get this graph:

```
library(h2o)
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)

# create data

x <- rnorm(10000,sd=3)
y <- 2*x + rnorm(10000,sd=0.4) + 0.3*rt(10000,5) -0.1*x^2 + 2.4*sin(1.2*x)
plot(x,y, main="h2o model vs keras model with h2o weights" )

df <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)

# apply h2o fit to data

h2o.init()
h2odf <- as.h2o(df)


model <- h2o.deeplearning(x = 1, y = 2,
                    training_frame = h2odf,
                    hidden = c(100,10),
                    activation = "Tanh",        # use "Rectifier" for relu
                    export_weights_and_biases = TRUE,
                    export_checkpoints_dir=getwd(),
                    verbose=TRUE)

newdf <- as.h2o(data.frame(x=seq(-10,10,by=0.01)))

predict <- as.data.frame(predict(model,newdf))
lines(seq(-10,10,by=0.01),predict$predict,col=2,lwd=2)


# Get the weights from h2o and convert them into a format that tensorflow will accept

layers <- model@parameters$hidden
activation <- model@parameters$activation
weights <- list()

for(i in 1:(1+length(layers))){
    W <- as.matrix(h2o.weights(model,matrix_id=i))
    B <- as.array(as.vector(h2o.biases(model,vector_id=i)))
    colnames(W) <- NULL
    W <- t(W)
    weights[[2*i-1]] <- W
    weights[[2*i]] <- B
    
}



# set up Keras model with the same layers and activation functions

k_clear_session()
model2 <- keras_model_sequential()
model2 %>% layer_dense(units=layers[1],input_shape=1,activation=tolower(activation))

for(i in 2:(length(layers))){
    model2 %>% layer_dense(units = layers[i],
                    activation = tolower(activation))
}
                
model2 %>% layer_dense(name="output",units = 1,activation = "linear")       # Can try tanh activation here, still doesn't make it right.    


# Inject h2o weights into the keras model

set_weights(model2,weights)

newdf <- data.frame(x=seq(-10,10,by=0.01))
predict2 <- predict(model2,as.matrix(newdf))

lines(seq(-10,10,by=0.01),predict2,col=4,lwd=2)
legend("topleft",legend=c("h2o","keras"),col=c(2,4),lwd=2)
```

Now one thing you might notice is that the blue line is a scaled down version of the red line.
I manually tweaked the scale until it matched up, and the scaling factor was 3 * x in the horizontal direction and 6.45 * y - 1 in the vertical direction. Weird scaling but ok.

```
plot(x,y, main="h2o model vs stretched keras model with h2o weights" )
s <- seq(-10,10,by=0.01)
lines(s,predict$predict,col=2,lwd=2)

lines(3*s,6.45*predict2-1,col=4,lwd=2)
legend("topleft",legend=c("h2o","keras"),col=c(2,4),lwd=2)
```

[image]

I tried the same process on a dummy classification task. I found that typically, the two lines wouldn't match up even under scaling.

[image: Classification]

```
# classification task

# generate binary classification data from the nonlinear function y_gen

x <- rnorm(10000,sd=2.6)
y_gen <-   20*dnorm(x,sd=1.2)*x #2*(0.6*x +0.2*sin(2*x)+0.1-0.01*x^3)

y <-vector(length=length(x))
for(i in 1:length(x)){
    y[i] <- sample(0:1,prob=c(exp(y_gen[i]),1),replace=TRUE)
}

y <- as.logical(y)
df <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)


# generate the h2o fit

h2odf <- as.h2o(df)


model <- h2o.deeplearning(x = 1, y = 2,
                    training_frame = h2odf,
                    hidden = c(100,10),
                    activation = "Tanh",
                    export_weights_and_biases = TRUE,
                    export_checkpoints_dir=getwd(),
                    verbose=TRUE)

newdf <- as.h2o(data.frame(x=seq(-10,10,by=0.01)))

predict <- as.data.frame(predict(model,newdf)[,3])
names(predict) <- "y"

plot(x,1-exp(y_gen)/(1+exp(y_gen)),main=c("h2o model vs keras model with h2o weights","classification test"))
lines(seq(-10,10,by=0.01),predict$y,col=2,lwd=2)


layers <- model@parameters$hidden
activation <- model@parameters$activation
weights <- list()

for(i in 1:(1+length(layers))){
    W <- as.matrix(h2o.weights(model,matrix_id=i))
    B <- as.array(as.vector(h2o.biases(model,vector_id=i)))
    colnames(W) <- NULL
    W <- t(W)

    
    if(i == 1+length(layers)){
        weights[[2*i-1]] <- as.matrix(W[,2])    # h2o output for a classification task is of length 2. value 1 is the negative probability, value 2 is the positive probability.
        weights[[2*i]] <- as.array(B[2])        # so here we only need one of them so we take only one of them
    } else {
        weights[[2*i-1]] <- W
        weights[[2*i]] <- B
    }   
}



# set up tensorflow

k_clear_session()
model2 <- keras_model_sequential()
model2 %>% layer_dense(units=layers[1],input_shape=1,activation=tolower(activation))

for(i in 2:(length(layers))){
    model2 %>% layer_dense(units = layers[i],
                    activation = tolower(activation))
}
                
model2 %>% layer_dense(name="output",units = 1,activation = "sigmoid")

set_weights(model2,weights)

predict2 <- predict(model2,as.matrix(newdf))

lines(seq(-10,10,by=0.01),predict2,col=4,lwd=2)
legend("topleft",legend=c("h2o","keras"),col=c(2,4),lwd=2)
```

**I suspect there is something funny with the way h2o sets up its activation layers**. H2o doesn't allow nearly as much 'under the hood' access as keras, so I've been so far unable to look at the inner goings on in the h2o model. For instance, how is h2o able to do regression on data that extends beyond (-1,1) with only tanh activation functions?

I've tried the above code with ReLu as well as Tanh, and I've tried altering the final layer of the keras model from tanh tanh to linear, to no avail.

My questions are:

**How does the h2o model give different results to the Keras model even when the same weights are used? What goes on under the hood when h2o is performing a prediction?**

and

**is there any other basic mistake I made when attempting to convert the weights?**

Comment: Perhaps h2o performs automated standardization / scaling on input and output?